# ImportError: No module named 'usuarios'

Tags: python, import

The following tree of files and directories:

```
-master_python
  -20-proyecto-python
     -usuarios
         - __pycache__
         - __init__.py
         - acciones.py
         - usuario.py
     
     -main.py
     -database.sql
```

In the file acciones.py:
It is in here were i have de issue "No module named 'usuarios'. I also tried using "from usuarios import usuario as modelo. Code doesn't run.

```
import usuarios.usuario as modelo
```

class Acciones:

```
def registro(self):
    print("\n Porfavor registrese en el sistema: ")

    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
    apellido = input("Ingrese el apellido: ")
    email = input("Ingrese el email: ")
    password = input("Ingrese la contraseña: ")

    usuario = modelo.Usuario(nombre,apellido,email,password)
    registro = usuario.registrar()

    if registro[0] >= 1:
        print(f"Perfecto {registro[1].nombre} te has registrado con el email {usuario[1]}.email ")
    else:
        print("Error al registrarse")

def login(self):
    print("Ingrese sus datos para iniciar sesion: ")
    email = input("Ingrese el email: ")
    password = input("Ingrese su contraseña: ")
```

enter code here

in usuario.py:

```
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd ="",
    database = "master_py",
    port = 3306
)

cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)
```

class Usuario:

```
def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, email, password):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.apellido = apellido
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

def registrar(self):
    fecha = "01-01=2021"
    sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (null,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    usuario = (self.nombre, self.apellido, self.email, self.password,fecha)

    cursor.execute(sql,usuario)
    database.commit()

    return [cursor.rowcount, self]

def identificar(self):
    return self.nombre
```

in main.py:

```
    print("""
Acciones disponibles:
    -Registro
    -Login
""")
```

In the next line VScode marks me as an error the import of 'usuarios' but code runs.
from usuarios import acciones

```
x = acciones.Acciones()

accion = input("Seleccione una opcion: ")


if accion == "Registro" or accion == "registro":
    x.registro()

elif accion == "Login" or accion == "login":
    x.login()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the question, but I think you only need to type `import usuario as modelo` or `from usuario import <anyClassOrFunction>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a module that is part of the same package. Just try 'import usuario as modelo' in acciones.py and it should work.

Comment: @MaeoG98: Please put comments on answers, rather than edits. Nobody can see your reply now except me :)

Comment: The comment was: "I tried 'import usuario as modelo' and now i have the same error but it says 'no module named 'usuario' '"
To be sure: in what file did you try this and in what file are you getting this error?

Comment: The error is in the directory usuarios in the file 'acciones.py' and i get the same error i "main.py" outside the directory usuarios, as i do "from usuarios import acciones"

Comment: If you run the file acciones.py only (so not as part of the package), does the error still persist? Otherwise, can you try to put "import usuarios" in the main.py and "import acciones" and "import usuario" in the \__init\__.py?